# Flask API returns 'empty ImmutableMultiDict' even when the file is successfully sent through angular code

Tags: python, angular, flask

I am using Python 3.7 and Angular 13. I am sending a file from Angular UI to Flask,python API.
My Angular html code is as below:

```
 <form id="basicForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload" method="post">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="mt-1 text-dark rounded">
                <h2 align="center" style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;">Chemical Insights</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="inputfileForm" *ngIf="flag==1" class="tabcontent">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file" class="control-label mb-2"
                            style="margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom:2px; font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;">File with CAS
                            number </label> <i class='fa fa-info-circle' data-toggle="tooltip"
                            title="Please upload the .txt file in agreed format." data-placement="right"></i>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" accept=".txt" name="file"
                            (change)="onFileChange($event)">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 mt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!isFileUploaded"
                            (click)="handleFileInput()">Upload</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
           
    
        </div>
    </form>
```

component.ts file is as below:

```
  flag: number = 0;

   fileToUpload!: File | Blob;
  isFileUploaded : boolean =false;
  fileUploadStatus: string | null = '';


  onFileChange(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length == 1) {
       this.fileToUpload=event.target.files[0]

      
      this.isFileUploaded = true
      console.log(event)
    }
    else if(event.target.files.length >1 ){
      this.isFileUploaded = false
    }
    else{
      this.isFileUploaded = false
    }
  }

  handleFileInput() {
    this.fileUploadStatus=''
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.fileToUpload);
    this.chemicalDashboardDataRefreshService.UploadFileToInputFolder(formData, ()=>{
     this.fileUploadStatus = this.chemicalDashboardDataRefreshService.readFileUploadStatus()
      if(this.fileUploadStatus == "Success"){
        alert('File upload successful. Please click on execute to retrieve refreshed data')
      }
      else{
        alert('Some error occurred while uploading the file. Please contact ERM team')
      }
    })  

  }
```

My http call request is as below where urlpasteInputFileInSharedDrive has the API's link:

```
 UploadFileToInputFolder(formData: FormData, callback?: any) {
    debugger;
    // let input ={"file":FileToCopy}
    this.httpClient.httpPostRequest(this.urlpasteInputFileInSharedDrive, formData).subscribe(
      response => {
        let res = response as any;
        if (res.Response_Status && res.Response_Status == "Success") {
          this.fileUploadStatus = "Success"
          console.log("Success")

          if (typeof callback == "function") {
            callback();
          }
        }
        else if (res.Response_Status == "Exception") {
          console.log(res.Response_Message)
          
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
      })
  }
```

Python Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/pasteInputFileInSharedDrive',methods=['GET','POST'])
def pasteInputFileInSharedDrive():
    try:
        print('Hi')
        Result=dict()

        a=request.files
        print(type(a))
        print(a)

        
        
        
        return {"Response_Status":"Success","Response_Message":"Success"}



    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
```

When I execute this, I get the below output as error:

````
Hi
<class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>
ImmutableMultiDict([])


**```

When I receive the file as (in the python code)
````

a=request.files['file']

```
I get the below error:
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
 - - [12/Jan/2024 13:29:11] "POST /pasteInputFileInSharedDrive HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1842, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\VirtualEnvironment\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2134, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function for 'pasteInputFileInSharedDrive' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended
without a return statement.
```

Comment: easier to just get the form, like let form = document.getElementById('basicForm')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);

Comment: that generally would send a files[] array... notice that in your flask code you are checking for request.files.  That's pretty standard, as there could be multiple files.  When you append (formData.append("file", this.fileToUpload);  it's sending a single name/value... name is 'file', value is presumably a blob.  So either send normal form data that would be a files[] array, or maybe check for request.file.  Value of request.file in that case would be the file blob... so just a = request.file

Comment: @pcalkins When I try this, it says 'Request' object has no attribute 'file'.

Comment: When I try sending the form itself, the error message is - 
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: try removing this line from the form: enctype="multipart/form-data"... the formData object will set enctype automatically.  You should probably also leave the action blank and handle on submit... (or return false, or use preventDefault... just to be sure there's no double-post)  Also not sure (click) is the event you want there... probably on onchange... so that it fires once the input's value is there.